# SQL Server Broker: How to modify contract?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

How do I add a new message type to an existing contract?

`CREATE CONTRACT`and `DROP CONTRACT` commands exist, but no `ALTER` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/379453/add-alter-contract-command-to-change-ssb-contract-defination):-

> A poor workaround to this would be to version all changes as new
>   contracts but that would require an additional service and queue and
>   existing conversations would not be able to benefit from the new
>   message type.
>
> I highly recomend support for an alter contract command but also add
>   support for SSDT to issue an alter command instead of drop/create.
>
> I highly reconsideration of this request. Or at a minimum: Add a check
>   and error message to be raised from SSDT whenever any conversation
>   exists that uses that service and/contract before dropping in a
>   similar way that SSDT checks for existing data in a table before
>   dropping said table. This would at least help raise awareness of this
>   side-effect and would have prevented deployment headaches.

Answer (score 6):

`ALTER CONTRACT` is not amiss due to omission, is missing **by design**. This is exactly like asking to change COM interfaces: is not supported, because the interface is a *contract*. If one party changes the interface, it breaks the contract and will cause the other party to crash when calling the wrong [v-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) entry. Exactly the same reasoning was applied in Service Broker design: one party cannot change (`ALTER`) the contract and start sending some new messages the other party does not expect, it will cause it to crash (error in the message processing procedure). **Contracts are immutable**.

If you say 'but I can `ALTER` the other party too' then you are not considering real use cases, when the other party is remote and often under a different administrative control and not willing to change its contract(s). even when a change is possible, deploying a distributed change that requires many side to roll out new bits is just asking for (unnecessary!) downtime.

Changes in communication pattern must be deployed as *new* contracts. Services can implement multiple contracts, and adding a new contract to a service (via [`ALTER SERVICE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176036.aspx)) *is* supported. Changes in distributed apps are rolled out by deploying new contract(s) while still supporting old one(s), then retiring old contract(s) (ie. *overlap*).